# Program crashes in Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008

I code in C# using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7. But when I build release and bring it to Windows XP, it crashes and suddenly quits the program with no exception.

Debugging on XP or release at Windows 7 works without and probles. It runs good?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're 100% certain the XP machine runs the same .NET framework you're targeting?

Comment: What does it mean that "crashes"? Can you post the exact message being displayed on the crash?

Comment: And what kind of project is it?

Comment: Yeah it's run on .NET 3.5. I run visual 2008 on XP and compile these code. It's run ok when i press F5 and it's die when i use Ctr + F5(without debug). No message displayed here. Just die and close all form

Comment: The program input two files and it's run ok. I use thread to show progressbar when I read input. It's die on it. Just die when I run release(Ctr + F5) on XP

Comment: You'll have to debug it all by yourself without showing us some code. Firstly, check the Event Viewer. Secondly, bind an event to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and see if that gets hit.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing in the event viewer either?

Comment: Yeah I have checked event viewer. No error happens

Comment: That's not possible. If the program closes due to an uncaught error, there *must* be an entry in the event log (make sure that it can dynamically change its size).